# Filter XML with E4X

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

I have this XML:

```
public var translations:XML = 
                <translations>
                    <firstName>
                        <en>first name</en>
                        <fr>prénom</fr>
                    </firstName>
                    <lastName>
                        <en>last name</en>
                        <fr>nom de famille</fr>
                    </lastName>
                </translations>
```

I would like to reduce it to the below:

```
<translations>
    <firstName>first name</firstName>
    <lastName>last name</lastName>
</translations>
```

In the above I have removed the `en` & `fr` nodes, I have consolidated the string from `en` into their place. I know I'm able to do this with a for loop but I'd prefer an E4X query if possible.

Comment: E4X is great to make requests in an XML but I don't think it's useful to create or edit one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the whole idea to be able to iterate over E4X Xml is to be able to have AS operators useful for Xml. Even Adobe's own page (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html) suggests using loop. In effect, I don't think you can accomplish this via '..', '@', '[]' operators.